# Example of path connected metric space whose hyperspace with Vietoris topology is not path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, path-connected

I believe the space must be compact and connected in order to guarantee its hyperspace with the Vietoris topology is path connected, but I cannot come up with or find any counterexamples.

Comment: I don't know much about these topologies, but I've shown before that the compact subsets of a path connected compact metric space are path connected in the Hausdorff metric. I couldn't come up with a counter-example, but I don't think it's true if the metric space is not compact (the proof I came up with certainly didn't work.)

Comment: The hyperspace of closed sets or compact sets of $(X,d)$? These are quite differently behaved. If $H(X)$ (ie non-empty closed sets in the Vietoris topology) is $T_4$, then $X$ must be compact Hausdoff e.g. $H(X)$ for non-compact $X$ is hard.

Comment: If $X$ is a compact connected locally connected metric space, $H(X)$ is homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, so path-connected.

Comment: [In this post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7t440f7h1544258_hausdorff_hyperspace_is_pathconnected) it is claimed that $X$ compact and connected implies $H(X)$ is path-connected. Recall that the Hausdorf metric induces the Vietoris topology for compact metric spaces.

Comment: As I explain in my answer: there *is* a counterexample for the compact sets hyperspace but not for the closed sets hyperspace.

Answer (score 4):

[This paper](https://polipapers.upv.es/index.php/AGT/article/viewFile/2040/2164) starts with some useful references. Borsuk and Mazurkiewicz already showed in 1931 that if $X$ is a compact and connected metric space, $H(X)$, the hyperspace of all non-empty closed (or equivalently, compact) in the Vietoris (or Hausdorff-metric, if you prefer) topology is path-connected (and still compact connected and metrisable of course). The same holds for the hyperspace of subcontinua $C(X)$, as well. Of course if $H(X)$ is path-connected, it is connected and then $X$ is connected as well, so connectedness of $X$ is necessary. If $X$ is not compact, $H(X)$ would not be metrisable (not even normal).

So to find a path-connected metric $X$ with non-path-connected $H(X)$, we need a non-compact $X$. Then the question becomes: do we look at $H(X)$, the closed sets, or $K(X)$, the subspace of compact non-empty sets of $X$. The latter space is metrisable (using the Hausdorff metric which induces the same topology on this set as its subspace topology from the Vietoris topology), the former is not.

The paper I linked to, answers precisely these questions in theorems 3.1 and 3.3:

For metrisable $X$, the hyperspace $K(X)$ of compacta in the Vietoris topology is path-connected iff each compact subset of $X$ is contained in a continuum (compact connected subset). Example 3.2 provides an example of a path-connected subset of the plane that fails this property.

Also, $H(X)$ (the closed subsets) is path-connected iff $X$ is continuum-wise connected (any two points $x \neq y$ lie in a subcontinuum of $X$), so there a path-connected $X$ will have a path-connected $H(X)$.